# Como definir um stylesheet para um widget sem afetar os seus widgets filhos em PyQt5?

Tags: css, pyqt-5

Estou criando uma janela com PyQt5 Framework e preciso adicionar a ela uma imagem de background. Para isso, estou definindo o seu *stylesheet* dessa forma:

```
mainWindow.setStyleSheet('background-image: url("./MyImage.png");')
```

O problema é que a imagem é adicionada para a `MainWindow` e para seus *widgets* filhos, como o `QLineEdit` e o `QPushButton`. Eu gostaria de saber como eu posso fazer essa alteração no *stylesheet* da janela, sem afetar os outros *widgets*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode dar um nome ao widget e especificar no QSS:

```
QMainWindow#janelaEspecial {background-image: url("./MyImage.png");}
```

Tudo que herda de Object na Qt pode receber nome, com `setObjectName`

```
mainWindow.setObjectName('janelaEspecial')
```

E neste caso você pode setar isso no CSS/QSS global se preferir, juntando várias definições num lugar só.

Lembrando ainda que o QSS é um "artifício" da Qt, você também pode
usar os métodos nativos e definir um QBrush com um QPixmap de fundo, sem usar estilos.